# Is there a way to adjust colors of a specific window?

Tags: windows, brightness, contrast, gamma

Is there a (Windows) program or something that will allow the user to adjust the brightness/contrast/gamma of a specific window rather than the whole screen?

As a use-case scenario, imagine having a web-page showing on one half of the screen, and another program taking up the rest of the screen. This other program uses the default Windows colors (e.g., white background), so it may be glaringly bright. Alternately, the web-page may be too dark to see. Adjusting the monitor or video-card settings would affect everything which will be no good. Adjusting the default Windows colors is, at best, inconvenient. Instead, there needs to be a way to set the colors of one of the windows to equalize the whole screen.

Comment: Did you mean for the `[windows]` tag to pertain to the operating system or graphical elements? You did not mention a platform in your question.

Comment: Windows (XP/7/etc.)

Comment: i don't think so......not because of windows.....i don't think any monitor allows different brightness levels at the same time.

Comment: @tumchaaditya, it would not be up to the monitor, it would be up to the software. It is trivial enough to adjust the brightness, gamma, contrast, and individual colors for the whole screen at the software level. I can't imagine it would be impossible to force a specific window to use a different set of colors.

Comment: For clarity, I am not talking about the *monitor’s* brightness/contrast settings or the backlight, I am talking about the actual color of the pixels that are sent to the video-card. It definitely *should* be possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Stardock's [Windowblinds](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CHAQjBAwBQ&url=http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/&ei=rjDmT5HvA-yr2AX8yvHbCQ&usg=AFQjCNHTtMUnLKpyjepu6OgWKXWGkPoJSg&sig2=Fk6F8tW3BGa0t618Bqwzcw) can help you?  I'm pretty sure that it can do window color adjustments (not just border and decoration).  Although I was never actually able to use it (this was a long time ago on a very old computer), I do seem to remember options relating to individual window colors.